# Has a batter practice to write Makefile(s) used to build docker images?

Tags: docker, makefile

In my application, there are several docker images to build.

And now, I use Makefile(s) to simplify the build actions:

My working directory:

```
|- dockerfiles
    |- platform
        |- Dockerfile
        |- Makefile
    |- policy
        |- Dockerfile
        |- Makefile
    |- some other images to build
```

And the Makefile at platform is:

```
NAME=platform
WAR_PATH=../../build
WAR=${NAME}.war
IMAGE_NAME=inner.server:8000/containers/${NAME}:1.0.0
PORT=8080

IMAGE_ID=$(shell docker images ${IMAGE_NAME} -q)
RUNNING=$(shell docker ps --format "{{.Names}}" | grep ${NAME})

clean:
    if [ "${IMAGE_ID}" != "" ]; then \
        echo "remove image ${IMAGE_NAME}"; \
        docker rmi ${IMAGE_NAME}; \
    fi

copy:
    cp ${WAR_PATH}/${WAR} .
    unzip ${WAR} -d ${NAME}

build: clean
    docker build -t ${IMAGE_NAME} .
    if [ -f "${WAR}" ]; then \
        rm ${WAR}; \
    fi
    echo 'Docker镜像 Build 完毕'

push:
    docker push ${IMAGE_NAME}

stop:
    if [ "${RUNNING}" != "" ]; then \
        echo "stop ${NAME}"; \
        docker stop ${NAME}; \
    fi

run: stop
    docker run --rm -it ${IMAGE_NAME} bash

.PHONY: clean copy build push stop run
```

And the Makefile(s) at policy and other sub directory are **almost same, except the `NAME` and `WAR` variables**:

```
NAME=policy
WAR_PATH=../../build
WAR=${NAME}-v1.0.0.war
IMAGE_NAME=inner.server:8000/containers/${NAME}:1.0.0
PORT=8080

IMAGE_ID=$(shell docker images ${IMAGE_NAME} -q)
RUNNING=$(shell docker ps --format "{{.Names}}" | grep ${NAME})

clean:
    if [ "${IMAGE_ID}" != "" ]; then \
        echo "remove image ${IMAGE_NAME}"; \
        docker rmi ${IMAGE_NAME}; \
    fi

#... The other tasks are same as above.

.PHONY: clean copy build push stop run
```

My question is: **Can these Makefile(s) be simplify?**

A pain is: When I want to add a task, I have to add the task to all these Makefile(s).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, one simple way to do it is just define those variables in the individual makefiles, then [include a common makefile](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Include.html) for the rest.

For example, in `platform/Makefile` you have:

```
NAME=platform
WAR=${NAME}.war
include ../common.mk
```

and in `policy/Makefile` you have:

```
NAME=policy
WAR=${NAME}-v1.0.0.war
include ../common.mk
```

then in `./common.mk` you have the rest of the common parts of the makefile:

```
WAR_PATH=../../build
IMAGE_NAME=inner.server:8000/containers/${NAME}:1.0.0
PORT=8080
  ...
.PHONY: clean copy build push stop run
```

Comment: Thx! It works.  I don't known the `include` directive, ^ _ ^

Comment: Added a link to the documentation.